# how to start with google calendar api in android

Tags: android, google-calendar-api

I'm creating an application for android which will use google calendar api. I will be creating a scheduler which will be integrated to google calendar. However, im clueless to how I am going to start. Can someone please enlighten me and give instructions to how i will start?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd suggest that as a first step, you choose a Java/Android API wrapper library to use when interacting with Google Calendar. Yes, you can call their API directly but you'll save yourself a fair amount of frustration by using a set of pre-built wrapper objects.

The Google Calendar API uses OAuth authentication, which can be somewhat daunting if you haven't used it before. Ideally, the library you choose should include OAuth methods.

Google's OAuth playground (https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/) is a useful tool for getting started with the OAuth process.

To keep things simple, as a first step you might consider just building a Java app that interacts with Google Calendar so that you don't need to worry about the Android threading model, UI framework, etc., while you're getting familiar with how to use the API.

The Temboo library contains fairly helpful documentation on the Google Calendar API, and the Temboo Android SDK contains methods for interacting with Google Calendar. Take a look at https://live.temboo.com/library/Library/Google/Calendar/

(Full disclosure: I work at Temboo)

Comment: what do you mean by "Java/Android API wrapper library" sir?

Comment: When interacting with the gCal API (or any API) you basically have two choices. You can either construct and make the raw HTTP calls to the API in your own code, or you can use a pre-built library that allows you to interact with the API via Java objects rather than dealing with parsing the XML or JSON data returned by the API. For example, take a look at Google's own Java library for their API: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v2/developers_guide_java vs. their raw API reference: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/

Comment: I also just noticed that Google has a fairly decent "build your first app" guide, although it refers to using the raw API rather than a wrapper library. Still might be a useful resource: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/firstapp

Comment: yes, it uses the raw api which is still a bit confusing for me. Anyway, thank you so much sir! Will be looking at the information that you posted :)

Comment: [Google's oauth playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/) is awesome