# Sync Calendar Events with Participants in android

Tags: android, calendar, google-calendar-api, android-studio-2.2

I am working on a android app in which I have to sync the Calendar events into my app calendar. I have done it with the following code. How can i do it for 
event participants.

```
 public List<EventModel> readAndSaveCalendarEvent(Context context) {

    List<EventModel> events = new ArrayList<>();

    String[] EVENT_PROJECTION = new String[]{"calendar_id", "title", "description", "dtstart", "dtend", "eventLocation", "allDay", "_id"};
    String selection = "(deleted != 1)";
    Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse(CALENDAR_URI_BASE + "events"), EVENT_PROJECTION, selection, null, null);

    Integer contactsCount = cursor.getCount();
    if (contactsCount > 0) {
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {

            EventModel model = new EventModel();

            try {
                model.calendarId = cursor.getString(0);
                model.event_title = cursor.getString(1);
                model.event_description = cursor.getString(2);

                String startDate = cursor.getString(3);
                Long startDateLong = startDate == null ? null : Long.parseLong(startDate);
                model.start_date = startDateLong == null ? null : DateHelper.getUtcFormatInLocalTZ(startDateLong);
                model.startDate = startDateLong == null ? 0 : startDateLong;

                String endDate = cursor.getString(4);
                Long endDateLong = endDate == null ? null : Long.parseLong(endDate);
                model.end_date = endDateLong == null ? null : DateHelper.getUtcFormatInLocalTZ(endDateLong);
                model.endDate = endDateLong == null ? 0 : endDateLong;

                model.isAllDay = cursor.getInt(6) == 1;
                model.setEventIdLocal(cursor.getLong(7));
                events.add(model);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        cursor.close();
    }

    // save new data into local database

    // delete existing calendar events
    DatabaseHelper.getInstance().getEventRepository().deleteCalendarEvents();

    String userId = SharedPreferenceHelper.getInstance().getUserId();

    DatabaseHelper helper = DatabaseHelper.getInstance();
    for (EventModel model : events) {
        model.setEvent_type(EventType.Custom.name());
        model.setCalendar(true);
        model.setUser_id(userId);

        if(model.getDescription() != null){

            String value = null;
            String[] data = model.getDescription().split(",");
            if(data.length > 0){
                value = data[0];
            }

            if(value != null && value.equalsIgnoreCase(Constant.SYNC_FROM_SCHEDULE)){
                model.setScheduleByMe(true);  // because don't want to show on calendar
                helper.getEventRepository().create(model);

            } else {
                model.setScheduleByMe(false);
                helper.getEventRepository().create(model);
            }

        } else {
            model.setScheduleByMe(false);
            helper.getEventRepository().create(model);
        }

        // change date time zone
        model.start_date = DateHelper.utcDateFormated(model.startDate);
        model.end_date = DateHelper.utcDateFormated(model.endDate);
    }
    return events;
}
```

The problem is i want to get the Participants of the calendar event also but I am not able to get them. Some post suggested to pass the argument **attende** to the list of arguments but this however does not work.

Could anyone help me in getting the participants from the events added in google Calendar, any help would be appreciated.

Thanks In advance.

Comment: It is the same on how you get the events, you need to use the **Attendees** to get the participants. You can check this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20236373) on how to use Attendees in your code. Also check the Github in this answer. Note that participants is also like the attendees. And it is the one that you will get in your results. For more information about attendees, check this [link](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/concepts/).

Comment: thanks kendi  ,  I was able to get the attendees from the calendar in same as the events.

Comment: That's great...